# How to use JsonUtils.safeEval() in GWT

Tags: json, gwt

I've noticed that `JsonUtils.safeEval()` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` when fed a string of the form "400" only when running within the debug session. In production an exception isn't thrown and instead the string "400" is returned.

In the mean I'm passing **JSON** strings to this function but there are a number of server calls that return an integer or a string.

One work-around would be to change all servers return values to **JSON** values e.g.,

```
{"return" : 400}
```

Anyone got another approach?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation of [JsonUtils#safeEval()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html#safeEval(java.lang.String))

> **Throws:**
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - **if the input is not valid JSON**

Hence clearly if the input is not a valid JSON , it will throw that Exception. The simplest JSON string for `400` would be `{"anyKey": 400}` or `["400"]`.

Comment: Just to emphasize: `400` and `"hello world"` are not valid JSON. JSON needs to be an object or array; see http://json.org/ But JavaScript's `JSON.parse()` accepts such values (along with `null`, `true` and `false`), which is why it doesn't throw in production mode.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer May be post it as answer . +1

Comment: @ThomasBroyer... thanks for addressing my question. I suppose GWT is following the JSON spec but Javascript is more "liberal". Post your note as an answer and I think this would be a very useful gotcha for others.